# Getting summary data from graphite

Tags: graphite

I have created a dashboard using the data published from my application using statsd with a graphite backend. This has worked great for building nice data visualizations. (Kudos to etsy and others!)

Now I need to make a summary dashboard that will display a grid, more-or-less, that shows each stat with a count. (No graphs on this page but clicking on the stat name will take you to the graph.)

So, for example, I am collecting statistics for how many messages each node in our cluster recieves, processes successfully, fails to process. What I need is something like the following:

```
| Node Name     | Messages Recieved | Successful  |  Failed   |
| ------------- |:-----------------:| -----------:| ---------:|
| Node1         | 1126              | 1120        | 6         |
| Node2         | 1155              | 1100        | 55        |
| Node3         | 1124              | 1119        | 5         |
| Node4         | 1204              | 1198        | 6         |
```

I have a timespan selector on the toolbar and based on that selection these numbers should be updated to reflect the selected timespan. I'm having a hard time getting numbers that seem to aligne with what I expect. And in some scenarios with the summarize function I am getting decimal values back which does not seem to make sense to me.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the &format=raw to get these data for the grid?

Comment: @talonx I apologize for the delay. I am just using the graphite api. And I just simulated the type of data I would like to see. I have not been able to accomplish a summary by node as of yet.